# Magento 2 Migration: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: migration, magento2.3.2, magento-1.9.3.3

In Map Step some time after below type error showing

> Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than
>   'max_allowed_packet' bytes

**Source Magento : 1.9.3.3 

Destination Magento : 2.3.2**

How can solve above error

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: reference link=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes

Answer (score 6):

I've faced the same issue while migration.

You can fix this issue by following the below steps:

> Change the MySQL `max_pocket_size` from the MySQL console to
>   `1000000000`.

***run below query in MySQL console:***

```
set global net_buffer_length = 1000000;
set global max_allowed_packet = 1000000000;
```

**Hope it'll help!**

Comment: i have tried that not working for me

Comment: Also, change my.cnf or my.ini file under the mysqld section and set: max_allowed_packet=100M

Comment: i have changed that two time but still not working for me

Comment: Restart the MySQL server and apache 2.

Comment: We have to increase max_pocket_size for source mysql or destination sql?

Comment: @HaFizUmer you need to do it for both if you're using different MySQL server for the source and destination database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase **max_allowed_packet**. Please access to Database, run this command: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` to check what its number is then multiple it to 2 or 3 times as your wishes. To perform it, please run the command: `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=xxx`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue related to database caching, resulting in an error. To resolve this issue, I made adjustments to the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf or my.ini) specifically within the [mysqld] section.

By modifying the my.cnf or my.ini file and setting the max_allowed_packet parameter to a value of 100M, I increased the maximum allowed packet size to 100 megabytes. This adjustment allows MySQL to handle larger packets or queries without encountering limitations.

`max_allowed_packet=100M`